# How to compare an item in a queue to an item in a set?

Tags: python, queue, set

REDIT: Was trying to avoid just placing the entire block of code on the forum and saying fix it for me, but here it is, to simply the process of determining the error:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.6
import threading
import Queue
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse
from lxml.html import parse, tostring, fromstring

THREAD_NUMBER = 1


class Crawler(threading.Thread):

 def __init__(self, queue, mal_urls, max_depth):
    self.queue = queue
    self.mal_list = mal_urls
    self.crawled_links = []
    self.max_depth = max_depth
    self.count = 0 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) 

 def run(self):
    while True:
        if self.count <= self.max_depth:
            self.crawled = set(self.crawled_links)
            url = self.queue.get()
            if url not in self.mal_list:
                self.count += 1
                self.crawl(url)
            else:
                #self.queue.task_done()
                print("Malicious Link Found: {0}".format(url))
                continue
        else:
            self.queue.task_done()
            break
    print("\nFinished Crawling! Reached Max Depth!")
    sys.exit(2)

def crawl(self, tgt):
    try:
        url = urlparse(tgt)
        self.crawled_links.append(tgt)
        print("\nCrawling {0}".format(tgt))
        request = urllib2.Request(tgt)
        request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5,0")
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        data = opener.open(request)

    except: # TODO: write explicit exceptions the URLError, ValueERROR ...
        return

    doc = parse(data).getroot()
    for tag in doc.xpath("//a[@href]"):
        old = tag.get('href')
        fixed = urllib.unquote(old)
        self.queue_links(fixed, url)


 def queue_links(self, link, url):

    if link.startswith('/'):
        link = "http://" + url.netloc + link

    elif link.startswith("#"):
        return

    elif not link.startswith("http"):
        link = "http://" + url.netloc + "/" + link


    if link not in self.crawled_links:
        self.queue.put(link)
        self.queue.task_done()
    else:
        return


def make_mal_list():
"""Open various malware and phishing related blacklists and create a list 
of URLS from which to compare to the crawled links
"""

hosts1 = "hosts.txt"
hosts2 = "MH-sitelist.txt"
hosts3 = "urls.txt"

mal_list = []

with open(hosts1) as first:
    for line1 in first:
        link = "http://" + line1.strip()
        mal_list.append(link)

with open(hosts2) as second:
    for line2 in second:
        link = "http://" + line2.strip()
        mal_list.append(link)

with open(hosts3) as third:
    for line3 in third:
        link = "http://" + line3.strip()
        mal_list.append(link)

return mal_list

def main():
    x = int(sys.argv[2])
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    mal_urls = set(make_mal_list())
    for i in xrange(THREAD_NUMBER):
        cr = Crawler(queue, mal_urls, x)
        cr.start()


   queue.put(sys.argv[1])

   queue.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So what I've got going on here is a web spider, which first creates a set made of the lines of several text files which contain 'malicious links'. Then starts a thread, passing both the set of bad links, and sys.argv[1]. The started thread, then calls teh crawl function which retrieves an lxml.html parse from sys.argv[1], and then after parsing all the links out of that initial page, places them in the queue. The loop continues, with each link placed in the queue being removed with self.queue.get(). The corresponding link is then SUPPOSED to be compared against the set of bad links. If the link in found to be bad, the loop is supposed to output it to the screen and then continue on to the next link, UNLESS it has already crawled that link.

If it is not bad, crawl it, parse it, place its links into the queue, etc, incrementing a counter each time a link is crawled, and continuing until the counter reaches a limit determined by the value passed as sys.argv[2]. The problem is that, items it should be triggering the if/else statement for 'if url not in mal_list' are not, and links that have been placed in the 'crawled_already' list, are being crawled a 2nd, 3rd, and forth time anyhow.

Comment: How didn't it work? This appears to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Unless you have described your problem incorrectly, the queue here is completely irrelevant and you are having issues with the test `a not in x`. Is `a` a custom class with modified `__hash__` or `__eq__` methods? If not the code is fine, and you'll need to provide a better example of what's gone wrong.

Comment: You got me. That why I turned to the stack for help :) X is created by a function which opens several txt files and adds on the lines of said files in a list, creates a set of the list, and returns the set. I placed the test string at the top of one of the text files, and than ran the code. The do_something part, is actually a web spider function. It just kept right on spidering, instead of calling do_something_else.

Comment: @katrielalax: a is the item returned from queue.get(). The queue is comprised of, first sys.argv[1], which is supposed to be a URL, and then calls a function which continually populates the queue with URLs parsed from the resulting html of a lxml.html parse, and then opens said links from the queue, checking against teh set, etc.

Comment: paste the actual code. There's nothing wrong with what you pasted so far. Your explanation is cryptic.

Comment: Edited the code above to display the broken code segment.

Comment: Why don't you explain in English what you are trying to accomplish.  There are too many hidden moving parts here: `queue` and `mal_urls` are shared with main and if main changes either, you can abandon any hope of deterministic behavior.  Also, what does `crawl()` do?  If it modifies `queue` or `self.crawled` directly the same thing applies.

Comment: Code posted in its an entirety, with a more concrete explanation of the problem I've been having.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand one detail of this code: the queue is marked as `task_done` if there is any new link found in `self.queue_links`, but not as a matter of course in `self.crawl`. I'd have thought that this code would make more sense:

```
def crawl(self, tgt):
    try:
        url = urlparse(tgt)
        self.crawled_links.append(tgt)
        print("\nCrawling {0}".format(tgt))
        request = urllib2.Request(tgt)
        request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5,0")
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        data = opener.open(request)
        doc = parse(data).getroot()
        for tag in doc.xpath("//a[@href]"):
            old = tag.get('href')
            fixed = urllib.unquote(old)
            self.queue_links(fixed, url)
        self.queue.task_done()
    except: # TODO: write explicit exceptions the URLError, ValueERROR ...
        pass

def queue_links(self, link, url):
    if not link.startswith("#"):
        if link.startswith('/'):
            link = "http://" + url.netloc + link
        elif not link.startswith("http"):
            link = "http://" + url.netloc + "/" + link
        if link not in self.crawled_links:
            self.queue.put(link)
```

I can't say, though, that I have a complete answer to your question.

---

Later: the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) for `Queue.task_done` suggest that `task_done` should be 1:1 with `Queue.get` calls:

> Queue.task_done()¶
>
> Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Used by queue
>   consumer threads. For each get() used
>   to fetch a task, a subsequent call to
>   task_done() tells the queue that the
>   processing on the task is complete.
>
> If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have
>   been processed (meaning that a
>   task_done() call was received for
>   every item that had been put() into
>   the queue).
>
> Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items placed in
>   the queue.

Were you getting [uncaught] `ValueError` exceptions? It looks like this might be so.